# Find missing rows in one table based on another table in Sqite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, left-join, common-table-expression, exists

I have two tables, `tournaments` and `pinsheets`. The tables looks as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "pinsheets" (
    "tournament"    INTEGER,
    "year"  INTEGER,
    "course"    INTEGER,
    "round" INTEGER,
    "hole"  INTEGER,
    "front" INTEGER,
    "side"  INTEGER,
    "region"    INTEGER
);
```

Sample of data:

```
2   2015    6   1   1   18      C
2   2015    6   1   2   8   4   L
2   2015    6   1   3   22      C
2   2015    6   1   4   45  4   R
2   2015    6   1   5   26  6   L
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE "tournaments" (
    "tournament"    INTEGER,
    "year"  INTEGER
);
```

Sample:

```
2   2015    
2   2016    
2   2017    
2   2018    
2   2019
```

Table `tournaments` contains of all the theoretical possible data. The actual collected information is saved in `pinsheets`. I want to loop over `tournaments` and see which observations I am missing. Basically the method should be as follows:

- get tournament/year combination
- check for round {1, 2, 3, 4} whether the tournament/year/round combination exists in `pinsheets`

My unsuccessful attempt:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM tournaments t
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM pinsheets pin
    WHERE  t.tournament = pin.tournament
    AND t.year = pin.year 
    AND (pin.round = 1 
            OR pin.round = 2
            OR pin.round = 3
            OR pin.round = 4)
            )
```

Desired output:

```
tournament   year   round
2   2015    3
2   2016    2
2   2017    2
```

Comment: pin sheets has no column round, but i think you are looking for pin.r1 = t.round. can you add some data for the tables, that fit the wanted result. see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for guidance

Comment: Basically you can ignore R1, R2, R3, R4 from `tournaments`. The values represent something different. However, there are always 4 rounds. So I was thinking about specifying these hard-coded in the query. I will add some data from the tables

Comment: ok even ignoring r1-r4, tournaments has tournament  2 and pinsheets has alll 6 as tournanet, so we can't get a match and i can't even guess what the result round 3 should even mean

Comment: I removed the R1-R4 columns to remove the noise. The samples were part of larger table and were not necessarily related. The goal is to check for each tournament-year-round-combination whether there are matches in `pinsheets`. The values for tournament and year are obtained from `tournaments`. round can be 1, 2,3, or 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `CROSS` join of `tournaments` to all the possible values of `rounds` (which can be obtained with a `CTE`):

```
WITH rounds(round) AS (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4))
SELECT t.tournament, t.year, r.round
FROM tournaments t CROSS JOIN rounds r
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM pinsheets p
  WHERE (p.tournament, p.year, p.round) = (t.tournament, t.year, r.round)
);
```

Or, with a `LEFT` join to `pinsheets`:

```
WITH rounds(round) AS (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4))
SELECT t.tournament, t.year, r.round
FROM tournaments t CROSS JOIN rounds r
LEFT JOIN pinsheets p
ON (p.tournament, p.year, p.round) = (t.tournament, t.year, r.round)
WHERE p.tournament IS NULL;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/wwFAQT6-).